# When viewing an svn repository through Apache in a web browser, is there a way to specify an old revision in the URL?

Tags: apache, svn

I think the question says it all. I am using a server that exposes an svn repository through HTML, and am wondering if I can specify a previous revision of files when linking to it. I believe the server uses Apache and mod_dav, but am not sure as I don't administer it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [old thread](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-08/0858.shtml) on the SVN mailing list asking a similar question. Tacking on the `!svn/bc/###/` bit seems to work on one repo I have access to, but it seems it's implementation-specific.